# excel COUNTIF formula

Tags: excel, count, formula, countif

I have a spread sheet with a colomn with the following formula copied down

```
=IF(L3 = "N/A","No Action",(IF((J3<>""),(IF((K3<>""),(IF((K3>J3),"FALSE","TRUE")),"N/A")),"")))
```

which gives me the results below in colum "M"

TRUE
TRUE 
FALSE
No Action
N/A
N/A
No Action
N/A
N/A
No Action
No Action
No Action

So i used the following formula in another sheet

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!M:M,"N/A")` which gives "4"
`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!M:M,"No Action")` gives "5"

how ever `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!M:M,"FALSE")` or `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!M:M,"TRUE")`

Give the result "0"

I think this is due to "TRUE and FALSE" being key words in excel but is there a way I can get excel to count the cells with these values in with out renaming them?

Comment: I answered this one my self, removed the "" from the original formula around the TRUE and FALSE words, =IF(L3 = "N/A","No Action",(IF((J3<>""),(IF((K3<>""),(IF((K3>J3),"FALSE","TRUE")),"N/A")),""))).

Comment: I did the same, not seeing your comment. When switched to '=IF(L3 = "N/A","No Action",(IF((J3<>""),(IF((K3<>""),(IF((K3>J3),FALSE,TRUE)),"N/A")),"")))' it worked as expected. It worked the same whether the countif had "TRUE" or TRUE. This seems to confirm your notion that the strings True and False behave differently because they are keywords.

Comment: yep that's what I got, cheers for looking at it as well for me. I Must remember to be more careful when using key words. Still its all on the learning cure

Comment: FWIW, you can change L3 formula to this for the same results `=IF(L3 = "N/A","No Action",IF(J3<>"",IF(K3<>"",K3<=J3,"N/A"),""))`

Answer (score 1):

Please see [MS Excel: COUNTIF Function (WS)](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php)

You should change criteria to **"=TRUE"** like this

**=COUNTIF(A1:A11;"=TRUE")**

Answer (score 0):

please use the below formula

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A11,"=TRUE")
```